# Retrieving an XPath Text from a Web Element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a task where I need to retrieve the following text in black color highlighted in yellow. It is not within any tags and has no attribute. Once you locate a web element through the Inspect option, how do you retrieve that text?  Also, what is it called when there is a text outside of a tag?
[image]

Comment: Just noticed the xpath tag.  Do you need it to be by XPath, as I often personally stay away from that selector unless I have no other choice.

Comment: Hi the test is in span tag , what have you tried so far? And what failed

Comment: Please mention the tool and programming language

Answer (score 1):

This is just the innerText.  If you were to use something like 
`string innerText = _browser.FindElement(By.ClassName("test-id__field-label")).Text;` 
the inner text (Duration) would be returned

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to achieve it since you have mentioned XPath, I'll just write how you could get to that text or get that text

```
string duration = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='test-id__field-label']").Text;
```

or

```
WebElement duration = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='test-id__field-label']");
string duration_text = duration.Text;
```

To find the element with that text

```
WebElement duration = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Duration']");
```

Answer (score 1):

xpath: //span[@text() = 'Duration']
css : span[class = 'test-id__field-label']
if you are using **selenium** then
class : driver.findelement(by.class("test-id__field-label");
if you are using **Portractor**
class: element(by.className("test-id__field-label"));